# How to add my Android app show in send list?

Tags: android, send

I implement an app.
It can upload photos to my own server.
I want to let my app can list in send list when implement below code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(FilePath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add following in your manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
</intent-filter>
```

Your manifest should look something like follow.

```
<application android:name="MyApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.example.arcasample.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks. But my app how to get the photo's path?

Comment: It can open my app. But I don't know how to get path.

Comment: @brian Dont club multiple questions in this thread.Rather post a new question with your new doubt.