# How can I add my app in the list of "SHARE" in android? (and receive the shared info)

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how can I make my app available at the share screen to receive shared information/content:

[image]

How may I program this (in Java, being NetBeans or Oracle IDE) ((IF its possible in App Inventor 2 would be pretty much better!)

Probably as I think i'll be needing a function like:

OnReceiveSharedContent()

and another statement to make it visible in the screen.

Comment: question unclear. You want your app to receive `ACTION_SEND` broadcasts? Then you'll need the `Intent filters` http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596882/how-to-add-my-android-app-show-in-send-list